# Git error after deploying React app to Firebase

Tags: reactjs, git, firebase, visual-studio-code

I am not sure if this is just a coincidence or my deploy to Firebase caused this. But after `git add .` and `git commit -m 'message'` I tried to push with `git push` and got this:

```
Missing or invalid credentials.
Error: connect ENOENT /run/user/1000/vscode-git-20522fd2e6.sock
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1056:14) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '/run/user/1000/vscode-git-20522fd2e6.sock'
}
Missing or invalid credentials.
Error: connect ENOENT /run/user/1000/vscode-git-20522fd2e6.sock
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1056:14) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '/run/user/1000/vscode-git-20522fd2e6.sock'
}
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/username/project-name/'
```

This is the first time it ever happened, and it was after I ran `npm run deploy` followed by `firebase deploy`. I am afaid I may have massively screwed up something as 'repository not found' shows. The deploy worked though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you did not identify the remote git repository to your terminal first.

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/username/project-name.git
```

and then,

```
git add .
git commit -m "force push"
git push origin master --force
```